# For which fields are the 1-dimensional algebraic groups known?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Given an algebraically closed field, or even a perfect one, a connected 1-dimensional algebraic group $G$ over the field $K$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbf G_a$ or $\mathbf G_m$.

> For which fields $K$ does this result still holds ?

By algebraic group over $K$, I mean an affine algebraic group, in the classical sense.

Comment: Do you mean to assume that $K$ is quadratically closed? Otherwise there are forms of $\mathbb{G}_m$ given by quadratic twists, namely norm-one tori in Weil restrictions $R_{L/K}\mathbb{G}_{m,L}$. (Like $S^1$ over $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: As soon as $K$ is not perfect, there are nontrivial forms of $\Bbb{G}_a$ - see P. Russel, *Forms of the affine line and its additive
group*, Pacific J. Math. 32 (1970), 527-539.

Comment: By the way, the article by Peter Russell mentioned by abx is online here: http://msp.org/pjm/1970/32-2/p19.xhtml

Comment: So, $K$ should be perfect and algebraically closed to avoid these examples? Probably, this is the answer to the question.